# Calling model's method from view works, but not from controller

Tags: joomla-3.x, fix-my-code, mvc

I am trying to call model's method from controller.

**controller.php**

```
if($view='myview'){   
      $model= $this->getModel('mymodel');  //on echo-prints class name of model
      $locations= $model->get('Locations');
      var_dump($locations);//prints NULL
      ...
}
```

**mymodel.php**

```
public function getLocations(){  
      $db=JFactory::getDBO();
      $query=$db->getQuery(true);  
      $query->select('distinct location');   
      $query->from('#__locations');
      $db->setQuery($query);  
      return $loc = & $db->loadObjectList();  
}
```

Why it's returning NULL in controller, however `getLocations()` working fine in **view.html.php**.

Comment: **Side note:** However `$db = JFactory::getDBO();` works in your model but it's better to define the db connection like so: `$db = $this->getDbo();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't do `$model->get('Locations')`. The correct syntax is to just call the method name: `$model->getLocations()`.

Using the `->get('Locations')` syntax is only valid in a view (because `get()` is a method of the view class).

This doesn't throw an error on the model, because it does also have a `get` method. However, it does a completely different task than being a reference for other methods.

--

Lots of other things that I want to note about the code:

1. Your if statement in the control should have two `=` signs. Otherwise you are setting the view to be that string (so it will always run).
2. Why do this: `return $loc = & $db->loadObjectList();`? Storing the object list in a local variable at the end is just odd. And you definitely don't need to store by reference by using the `&`. Just do `return $db->loadObjectList();`
3. This one may not be true in your case, but if the model and the controller are from the same set (i.e. have the same name) you can usually get away with just doing `$model = $this->getModel();` instead of `$model= $this->getModel('mymodel');` The controller already defaults to the model of the same name.

Comment: Nice one with the `get`. I missed that. :)

Answer (score 3):

There is very little background on what else is in the component.

You really need to check for database exceptions. See: [How to do SQL exception / error handling compatible with 2.5 and 3.x?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/495/how-to-do-sql-exception-error-handling-compatible-with-2-5-and-3-x)

I see two options here:

**1. Recommended**

You set up your debugger in your prefered IDE and look into the code to see what it does and where is the null coming from.

This will help you not only now, but also on the long run.

**2. May work**

Disadvantage of this method is that your code quality will continue to be poor and the next `null` you get will result into a new question asking for help.

Since it seems that `$model` is an instance of your model, the only chance I see if somehow `getLocations()` not being called or `loadObjectList()` returning a null as a result of a failed query. Not excluded is also a typo somewhere.

Comment: My first debugging step would have been an `exit` or `var_dump` in the model's `getLocations` method. That would likely show that the model never gets called.